# Cakephp and neo4j datasource

Tags: php, cakephp, neo4j, datasource, nosql

I have a question about the neo4j drivers.First of all, I am using CakePHP as a framework and Neo4j graph database.I want to connect neo4j and cakephp but there are no driver or datasource.I tried to implement Neo4j offical driver for Php but It's not worked because of namespaces.The Cakephp not found classes which is related or extended in that driver.How can I fix them? Also, If there are any datasource for cakephp how can I found them?

Comment: So how do you finally work with CakePHP and neo4j?
The accepted answer slightly help.

Comment: Yep, I wrote my own REST client.

Comment: Hey, i am trying to connect CakePHP and neo4j. I don't know how to start. Can you please help me ?

Comment: Yep I've solved the problem.It's easy to working with neo4j but only the logic is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to run faster i would just work with the neo4j api.

http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api.html

from your code make direct requests to the api. It is not much work and easier to maintain.

Comment: Yep, I thinked that also.I that faster than php-driver? Because, you must use cypher language in there? What do you think about that?

Comment: learning cypher language is simple. And it is better if you want to debug or learn about your data.